# Android NSD : Registration of service is not happening on emulator

Tags: android, dns-sd, nsd

I want to register a NSD service through the emulator app.  The emulator is running on my linux ubuntu machine connected to my local network.

I followed the instructions as listed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).

I am able to register the service when I run the app on my Nexus device. I have connected nexus device to same local network. I am using `avahi-browse --all` command to check the registered services. When I run this command after the app is run on the nexus device, I get an entry for the newly registered service.

Below is the output of the command run:

```
+   eth0 IPv4 NsdChatEmulator_3                             Web Site             local
+   eth0 IPv6 NsdChatEmulator_3                             Web Site             local
```

Here 'NsdChatEmulator_3' is name of the service.

But when I run the same app on emulator, it is running but the service is not registered.

Can someone have any idea what is the issue of using NSD on the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator has a limitation on multicast usage which is essential for NSD. Read the documentation below for more details

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html#networkinglimitations